# Insert Command Not Working

Tags: c#, insert, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbdataadapter

I use OleDbDataAdapter visually to connect to my .mdb database.
first of all: if I select two or more tables of my databse, the adapter doesn't build insert, delete and update commands and just builds select command.
second: when i select just one table , insert command doesn't work!
Here is my code (sth like that):

```
Myconnection.Open();
Myadapter.InsertCommand.CommandText="INSERT INTO name (sth,sth2) VALUES ('1', '2')";
Myadapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: When you say *doesn't work*, what exactly do you mean? do you get any error message?

Comment: No. But nothing happens. nothing have inserted

Comment: Sorry bro.. if you need help you'll have to provide more info/error message.. It's difficult to guess what the problem is

Comment: But there's no error message. even when i have syntax error in insert command, an exception is thrown. but whne there's nothing wrong, there's nothing done.

Comment: Where are you setting `Myadapter`'s OleDbConnection to Myconnection?

Comment: I said. visual studio does it. choose OleDbAdapter and OleDbConnection from "Choose Items..." menu of toolBox and you can add them

Comment: Have you tried setting the InsertCommand to a new OleDbCommand rather than just setting the CommandText? (Untested) 
`Myadapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO name (sth,sth2) VALUES ('1', '2')", Myconnection);`

Comment: Exception: the connection is closed

Comment: That example above was only meant to replace the second line in your example, not all of it!

Comment: Hi Feri73. What are the data types of `sth` and `sth2`? Also, what are their values before and after the query executes?

Answer (score 1):

Name is probably a reserved word and needs to be ticked

```
insert into `name` ( fld1, fld2 ) values ( '1', '2' )
```

Additionally, if your fields are numeric based, the data type would fail as '1' and '2' are character and probably causing it to choke.

One other point, from your feedback answer of no connection open.  When you created your "Insert" command object, did you set it's connection object?  It doesn't look like so from what you have

```
Myconnection.Open();
Myadapter.InsertCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
```

If the adapter was not set to the "MyConnection", it can't just assume which object reference to use.  What if you were connecting to completely different sources.

Comment: +1. Good catch. I am no OleDb wiz, but `name` could be a keyword!

Comment: @Feri73, see revised answer regarding confirmation of connection object to the insertCommand.